# JQuery .next() not picking up next element with selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked at the `JQuery` Documentation in relation to the `.next()` method and it states:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following
>   sibling of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery
>   object from the matching elements.
>
> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type
>   that we can pass to the $() function. If the immediately following
>   sibling matches the selector, it remains in the newly constructed
>   jQuery object; otherwise, it is excluded.

I'm trying to target an element within a div like so:

```
$("input[name='first-name'").keyup(function () {
    if (!name($(this).val())) {
        $(this).parent().next(".fa-times").removeClass('hide');
        $(this).parent().next(".fa-check").addClass('hide');
        $(this).css({
            "background": "rgb(237, 209, 209)",
            "color": "red",
            "border": "1px solid red"
        });
    } else {
        $(this).parent().next(".fa-times").addClass('hide');
        $(this).parent().next(".fa-check").removeClass('hide');
        $(this).css({
            "background": "rgb(209, 237, 209)",
            "color": "green",
            "border": "1px solid green"
        });
    }
});
```

The Markup is as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
    <div id="fname-input">
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap first-name">
            <input type="text" name="first-name" value="" size="40" maxlength="80" minlength="2" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false>
        </span>
        <i class="fa fa-times hide"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check hide"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can remove the class hide from `fa-times` in both cases using the line:

```
$(this).parent().next(".fa-times").removeClass('hide');
```

But for some reason I cannot pick up `fa-check`. I'm wondering is it because of this:

> If the immediately following sibling matches the selector, it remains
>   in the newly constructed jQuery object; otherwise, it is excluded.

If that is the case can anyone advise me on where I'm going wrong and the next best way to detect the next element with `fa-check` as it's class.

I'm working on a JS Fiddle now, will post as soon as it's working.

Comment: You are missing square bracket in your selector: `$("input[name='first-name'")`. It should be - `$("input[name='first-name']")`

Comment: Yes you're right, selector still works - tbf - I didn't expect selector engine to be that forgiving...

Comment: Yeah, bit shocked at that myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `fa-check` is not the next sibling the input's parent element. You can either use .siblings() or .nextAll()

The .next() will not fetch the next sibling matching the given selector, it will search only the next sibling element and then check whether that matches the given selector.

```
$(this).parent().nextAll(".fa-check").removeClass('hide');
$(this).parent().siblings(".fa-check").removeClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 1):

As `.fa-check` is not immediate next element, you cannot use `next()` to get that element.

[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Get the **immediately following sibling** of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get the correct element.

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".fa-times").removeClass('hide');
```